# Json files structure/format in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code (under Windows), my present Json files are displayed as the following :

[image]

I would them to be formatted as displayed below :

[image]

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-P -> format document?

Answer (score 12):

Open the json file and `SHIFT` + `OPTION` + `F` for mac

Answer (score 10):

Use `ALT-SHIFT-F` to auto format a json file in windows

Answer (score 4):

In 2022 it's **`Ctrl+Shift+I`** as stated on the [Visual Studio Code website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json#_formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Press **Ctrl-Shift-p** to format the documents. I don't know if this shortcut works on Windows, but it does on Linux.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I was trying to process a step in a tutorial where the author works on Mac. I will also try later to find an extension for the right format.

Answer (score 1):

On your Mac, you can do so by pressing **command**+**shift**+**p** and then type or select "**JSON: Sort Document**"

Answer (score 0):

Install a code formatting extension then save the file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install Prettier using the extensions, and then right click, select format document with and pick Prettier.

Answer (score 0):

**RIGHT CLICK and Select Source Action then JSON file will be converted to JSON format**

[image]